# See objc calls in call stack

Tags: objective-c

I am debugging a Objective-C application and would like to see the method calls in the ObjC library (for educational purposes!). What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to see the symbolic names of the methods?

Comment: Yes - thats right - preferably using GDB from command line

Comment: Just use the `bt` command in gdb.

Comment: Doesn't seem to give me the symbols from that library

Comment: You won't see `obj_msg_send()` in the trace because it invokes the method on the object by tail call optimisation.  Its stack frame effectively disappears.  Also, the library itself is almost certainly stripped so it won't have its debug symbols in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// print a stacktrace
NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]); // requires iOS 4
```

or

```
// print stacktrace using C functions
#import <execinfo.h>
#import <unistd.h>
void PrintStackTrace() {
  void *stackAdresses[32];
  int stackSize = backtrace(stackAdresses, 32);
  backtrace_symbols_fd(stackAdresses, stackSize, STDOUT_FILENO);
}
```

or set a breakpoint in XCode to pause the execution and then type GDB commands in the console or just look at the stack in the debug navigator tab.

Comment: Tried this - but the problem is that I don't see any ObjC calls in the stack trace

Comment: If you type `call (void)instrumentObjcMessageSends(YES)` you get a list of messages in `/tmp/msgSends-<PID>`. To get more detail you have to dig into assembler. Heading this way may be of help: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECSOMEASSEMBLY

Comment: is there a way to get call stack of main thread from bg thread?