# Get the object which called a method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

If I have a call from within a random class like this:

```
@implementation SomeClass

- (void) classMethodFoo
{
    int a = [SomeSingleton sharedInstance].aValue;
}

@end
```

Inside `SomeSingleton sharedInstance`, is there a way to get a reference to the object which called this method (without the called passing self as a parameter of course)?

Comment: Almost duplicate: [How to find out who called a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793999/how-to-find-out-who-called-a-method/1794051)

Comment: @DarkDust, no it is completely different question. This one is about particular instance of caller. Your link more about stack trace.

Comment: @Timur: In both questions, it's about "who called me". You can answer that only via the stack, and there's no reliable way for that.

Answer (score 7):

No, information about the caller isn't passed along automatically.

This is why `IBAction` methods, for instance, have a `sender` parameter, and why delegate methods often have a parameter that refers to the delegate's object.

Comment: I'd like to add that while it's possible to [get the call stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788850/see-objc-calls-in-call-stack) you can't get the calling object without platform dependent stack-walking (as far as I can see).

Comment: Also, it may be the case that no ‘object’ called that method. For instance, that method could be called from a function.

Comment: @Dark: Thanks for the link. I wasn't sure if it was necessary to include a disclaimer that it is actually possible if one is willing to dig into internals that one most likely doesn't want to dig into. :)